# Silverlight AutoCompleteBox takes a long time to respond on first "search"

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, autocomplete, delay

I have a Silverlight application which loads about 2000 objects of half a dozen fields into an AutoCompleteBox.  The filter is then set to search on any of four of the fields.  I've set it to begin searching after two characters.

However, when I type the second character (when the box is supposed to start populating) for the very first time after populating the List of objects, the AutoCompleteBox takes about 6-7 seconds to respond.

Any ideas on how I can optimize this?

Is there a way to create these visual elements right after the list is populated instead of waiting for the user to begin typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you alreay adjusted the MinimumPrefixLength propery? The more characters you require, the filtering will be better.

Right now, with a low prefix, you have 2000+ visual elements that are created, minus say one character of filtering, regardless of any other optimizations.

Another option is to implement your own background thread-filtering, but that defeats many of the purposes for the control (i.e. simplicity).

Comment: I've got the MinimumPrefixLength set to 2, which is where I'd like to keep it if possible.  Is there a way to create these visual elements after pulling in the list instead of waiting until the user starts to type?  I tried adding two common characters to the Text property after the list was specified as the datasource, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

It is bug in **AutoCompleteBox** control.

When DropDown is opened for the first time, **UI Virtualization** is not used and control creates all items.

To fix this you must set **MaxHeight** to **Grid** of dropdown **Popup** in AutoCompleteBox **ControlTemplate**. This is XAML part of this ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:AutoCompleteBox">
    <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
        ...

        <Popup x:Name="Popup">
            <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}" MaxHeight="450">
                <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderThickness="0" Background="#11000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="1.0" Padding="0">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#AADDDDDD" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="-1"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                        <ListBox x:Name="Selector" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This works for me.